# Create a single jar that will contain compiled classes and javadoc without Maven

Tags: java, jar, javadoc

When I build a jar with Eclipse, sometime I'd like to include source or JavaDoc with the .class files in a single .jar file.  I found how to do that with Maven.  Is it possible to do it just using Eclipse?

TIA,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import a maven project into Eclipse. That's one way. Just import your maven project and perform the maven steps you do to create you jar file.

You can also export a Java project, which includes the sources and all that you mentioned using Eclipse under the File -> Export option. You will see a wizard that allows you to choose the target (war, jar, ear, ...) and the resources that should be included.

Mode details: http://www.codejava.net/ides/eclipse/how-to-create-jar-file-in-eclipse